# What was the first adventure to use boxed text?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, history-of-gaming, narration

James Introcaso recently wrote a blog post titled, ["We Can Do Better Than Boxed Text"](https://worldbuilderblog.me/2019/04/11/we-can-do-better-than-boxed-text/), where he outlines the benefits and drawbacks of boxed text.

This has raised the question, who started it and **how long has boxed text been with us?**

I have reviewed the earliest published adventures but have not yet found boxed text. Those included:

- (1975) The first published D&D scenario of all time: the Blackmoor supplement for the "Temple of the Frog"
- (1976) The first standalone D&D module of all time: Palace of the Vampire Queen
- (1978) The first module printed with the first edition of the basic D&D set: In Search of the Unknown
- (1978) The first standalone module published by TSR G1: Steading of the Hill Giant Chief.
- (1979) The second module included in the D&D basic set: The Keep on the Borderlands

None of these have boxed text, which seems to suggest that it didn't arrive until after 1979.

**What was the first published adventure (module or periodical) in D&D history to use boxed text?**

Comment: I'll check my old modules and see if I can find a break.

Answer (score 4):

## The first published module by TSR to use boxed text is C1:The Lost Tomb of Tamoachan in 1980

The earliest module I have found with boxed text is the unicolor version of module C1. Here's the image linked at DriveThruRPG.

[image]

**Here is a screenshot of the very first boxed text** in that adventure. (Posting here as it fits [WotC's Fan Policy](https://company.wizards.com/fancontentpolicy), provisions of [Copyright Fair Use](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html), and precedent - but moderators let me know if there are other superseding provisions.)

[image]

**The authors were Harold Johnson and Jeff R Leason** making them, potentially, the first authors published by TSR who used boxed text. The module did not credit artists or a layout editor (if there was one.)

**This might not be the earliest boxed text in a module.** There is a prerelease version of this module that was used at Origins International Game Expo (known simply as ‘Origins’) in 1979 called: "Lost Tamoachan: Hidden Shrine of Lubaatum" Only [300 numbered copies were sold](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/modpages/c1.html) and it is a collector's item. I was unable to find a copy of this to review for boxed text - but this might actually be the first module with boxed text. (If you know someone with one please check!)

[image]